# Calling Azure Automation runbook as a task from Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-automation

I would like to call an azure automation runbook from Azure DevOps as a task.Perhaps a task is not avaible for this then can we create some sort of a trigger from a task and let that trigger the runbook?
eg: Create a file in blob storage and that can trigger an automation runbook?
If yes which trigger can I create from Azure DevOps? I could not find a blob trigger for runbook.

My goal is to run some tasks inside a VM throug Azure Automation (as it is a hardened VM that cannot be accessed from DevOps). So I create the VM through DevOps then I want to trigger runbook to take over(or run it as the next devops task).

Comment: Just a bit confused between the title and the content of the question. Could you elaborate a bit on the use case? You could try to create a task that would call the runbook via an HTTP post? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

> Calling Azure Automation runbook as a task from Azure DevOps

You could create a service connection with Azure Resource manager:

[image]

Then use the Azure powershell task to execute the powershell scripts:

[image]

You could check the document [USING AZURE DEVOPS PIPELINES WITH AZURE AUTOMATION](https://www.miru.ch/using-azure-devops-pipelines-with-azure-automation/) for some more details.

Comment: But how are the run book executed or run? In this example the DevOps is a CI/CD for installing runbooks right? What I am looking is to invoke the runbooks

Comment: @BlueClouds, I think you could execute the run book by the RETS API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/job/get-output#errorresponse